# Can't get my thread to execute with SetEvent and WaitForSingleObject

Tags: windows-ce

I'm trying to create a thread and let it run until my main signals it to start, which I think  is done with SetEvent. But the code in the thread is never executed. Below is the bare code I have stripped down of (I think) unrelated functions. Is the algorithm correct ?
Here is what I thought it did :

When in the main, the thread is created, which means it'll run in the background. When the event is set (SetEvent), the thread picks it up at WaitForSingleObject and then execute the code in the thread, right ?

```
HANDLE hThread;                                                     
HANDLE Event;

DWORD Thread()
{
while(1)
    {
    wait = WaitForSingleObject(Event, INFINITE)
    //This is where I want to execute something
    }
}


int _tmain()
{
    DWORD dw;
    int i;


    Event = CreateEvent(NULL,false,false,NULL);
    hThread = CreateThread(NULL,0,Thread,EventA,0,NULL);            

    while(1)
        {
        if (condition is correct)
            {
            SetEvent(Event);
            }


        CloseHandle(Thread);
        CloseHandle(Event);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for having read.

Answer (score 1):

Move CloseHandle lines out of the while loop.